# Showing convergence on a set with no metric defined on it.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

Suppose $S$ is a non-empty set and define $a:\mathbb{N} \to S$ by $a(n)=1$ for $n<1$ and $a(n)=2$ for $n \ge 1$. Show that $(a_n)$ is convergent.

$\exists 1 \in \mathbb{N} \ni \forall n \ge 1$, we have $a_n=a_1$. So $(a_n)$ is eventually constant $\Rightarrow (a_n) \to 2$. Thus $(a_n)$ is convergent.

I know that this implicitly assumes that $\forall \varepsilon>0$, there exists a $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n>N,d(a_n,a)<\varepsilon$.

However, I was wondering whether we can just use the definition of an eventually constant sequence to prove that $(a_n)$ is convergent.

I'm looking for a counterexample to show that we don't need the definition of convergence to show that a sequence is convergent on a set with no metric defined on it. Any insight would be appreciated!

Comment: Hello :) convergence is defined for sequences on topological spaces. And every metric space is a topological space. But you are right. It does not depend on the topology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, to show a property, you need the definition of that property. But note that convergence is defined in more general contexts than metric spaces. What we'd generally need though is a topology. If we only have a set, then typically very many topologies on it are possible, and the full notin of convergence depends on us agreeing which of thee topologies to consider. Perhaps to your delight, eventually constant sequences are convergent for *all* possible topologies; and the eventual constant turns out to be *a* limit of such a sequence (and for many nice topologies, *the* limit).